# Translating query comprehension to Enumerable extension methods in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, list-comprehension

How do I translate the following query to functional calls? I know the compiler does this behind the scenes but don't know how I would view the result

```
        var query = from item in Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
                    from item2 in Enumerable.Range(item, 10)
                    from item3 in Enumerable.Range(item2, 10)
                    select new { item, item2, item3 };
```

Comment: Are you asking "what is the translation of this particular query into a method chain?", or the more general question of "how can I see the method chain version of a LINQ query?" ?

Comment: Primarily asking about the former, but the latter is of interest as well

Comment: For the latter, it's not really an answer but I will offer up that ReSharper will do the conversion for you right in the IDE

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this case, it uses `SelectMany`, and a concept called *transparent identifiers* which preserve the existing range variables. So your query would translate to:

```
var query = Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
                      .SelectMany(item => Enumerable.Range(item, 10),
                                  (item, item2) => new { item, item2 })
                      .SelectMany(z => Enumerable.Range(z.item2, 10),
                                  (z, item3) => new { z.item, z.item2, item3 });
```

(In this case `z` is the transparent identifier. If there'd been a `where` clause or anything other than a `select` after the last `from` clause, another transparent identifier would have been introduced.)

The translations are all described in the [C# language specification, section 7.16](https://csharpindepth.com/articles/Specifications).